# Hyper-V PCIe Passthrough of GPU working (but not 100%)

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, graphics-processing-unit

I have managed to be able to passthrough a PCIe GPU (AMD RX580) into a Windows 10 Guest on a Windows Server 2016 Standard host.

The problem is that whenever the GPU will be used this error throws up:

[image]

The driver was installed through Windows update

[image]
[image]

**The PCIe passthrough was done using Powershell (Administrator):**

1. `Set-VM -Name "Parsec" -AutomaticStopAction TurnOff`
2. `Dismount-VmHostAssignableDevice -LocationPath
   "PCIROOT(0)#PCI(0301)#PCI(0000)" -force`
3. `Add-VMAssignableDevice -LocationPath
   "PCIROOT(0)#PCI(0301)#PCI(0000)" -VMName "Parsec"`
4. `Set-VM "Parsec" -GuestControlledCacheTypes $True
   -LowMemoryMappedIoSpace 2000MB -HighMemoryMappedIoSpace 8000MB`

What could be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today the best and most effective way to do this is through https://github.com/jamesstringerparsec/Easy-GPU-P

This will "passthrough" (although not dedicated passthrough); the GPU will be usable inside the VM through some kind of shared driver (not sure of the internals yet--but I've tested and it works like a charm)

Answer (score 1):

please follow this tutorial here
https://youtu.be/XLLcc29EZ_8?t=570

the script i used is below

```
$vm = "YOUR_VM_NAME_HERE"

Add-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm
Set-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm -MinPartitionVRAM 80000000 -MaxPartitionVRAM 100000000 -OptimalPartitionVRAM 100000000 -MinPartitionEncode 80000000 -MaxPartitionEncode 100000000 -OptimalPartitionEncode 100000000 -MinPartitionDecode 80000000 -MaxPartitionDecode 100000000 -OptimalPartitionDecode 100000000 -MinPartitionCompute 80000000 -MaxPartitionCompute 100000000 -OptimalPartitionCompute 100000000

Set-VM -GuestControlledCacheTypes $true -VMName $vm
Set-VM -LowMemoryMappedIoSpace 1Gb -VMName $vm
Set-VM –HighMemoryMappedIoSpace 32GB –VMName $vm
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you followed Microsofts TechCommunity Blog: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/virtualization/discrete-device-assignment-gpus/ba-p/382266

The last paragraph states that the CPU can hold back the GPU and you should set

```
Set-VM "Parsec" -GuestControlledCacheTypes $True
```